# Do I have to reinstall the app after renewing provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I do not have the Developer Program account right now. My application is for own use, and I found that I have to reinstall the application every week due to the expiration of the provisioning profile.

I wonder if I join the developer program, is it possible to renew the provisioning profile through developer.apple.com/account/ and allow me to use the application without reinstalling?

If possible, how often should I renew the provisioning profile, can I renew it before expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are enrolled in developer program. Your created provisioning profiles will be valid for one year.
Yes, you can renew it before you renew your developer program.
Your apps will be valid till one year. After that you can update your app with new provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Once you created a profile. It should work automatically if you have "Automatically manage signing" ticked in Xcode 9 under General tab for your app.

You normally have to set your team as well.

Also if you want you can go into settings and Accounts. Select your developer account ID and click download manual profiles.

Certificates last for a year.

Hope this helps.